# (apache httpclient) What is different thing in 3 code?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

//1
client.setConnectionTimeout(1000);

//2
client.getParams().setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 1000);

//3
client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(1000);
```

I want to know the main difference between this things?

Comment: You forgot to tag your question with the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

They are all the same

There is one `HttpClientParams` object which is created in or provided to the constructor of `HttpClient` and passed to the `HttpConnectionManager`

From there, the 3 ways are just a slightly different flows to setting the same parameter in the parameters object.

Answer (score 0):

For such issues have a look at the JavaDoc for the setConnectionTimeout method and the other ones. It is likely that some of them are deprecated/bad practice depending on the version you are using. As this is OpenSource you can also read the code and see for yourself what happens behind the scenes, this is the only way to know for sure.